# Why does getElementsByTag throw NullPointerException?

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing, android-sdcard

I'm trying to parse xml data from this URL:http://cloud.tfl.gov.uk/TrackerNet/LineStatus but am getting a `NullPointerException` on the line that read:

```
NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
```

Before I show the code, I'd just like to say whats going on. First I download the XML file to the SDCard in

```
saveToSdCard();
```

Then I retrieve it with

```
getDataFromSDcard();
```

Here is my code:
Main Activity:

```
public class DashboardFragment extends SherlockFragment {
private CardUI mCardView;

String TUBE_STATUS_URL;
String KEY_ITEM = "LineStatus";
String KEY_LINE = "Line";
String KEY_NAME = "name";
String KEY_STATUS_DETAILS = "StatusDetails";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_dashboard,
            container, false);

    // Get the URL's
    TUBE_STATUS_URL = "http://cloud.tfl.gov.uk/TrackerNet/LineStatus";

    // Find the cards in inflated layout
    CardUI cardGroup = (CardUI) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cardsview);
    fillCards(cardGroup);

    DownloadFeedsTask task = new DownloadFeedsTask();
    task.execute(new String[] { "" });

    return rootView;
}

private void fillCards(CardUI cardGroup) {
    // Fill cards with data
    // init CardView
    mCardView = cardGroup;
    mCardView.setSwipeable(true);

    // create a stack
    CardStack delayStack = new CardStack();
    delayStack.setTitle("Tube Lines with delays");

    // add cards to stack
    delayStack.add(new MyCard("Jubilee Line", MyCard.LINE_UNAVAILABLE));
    delayStack.add(new MyCard("Victoria Line", MyCard.LINE_AVAILABLE));
    delayStack
            .add(new MyCard("Piccadilly Line", MyCard.LINE_IN_MAINTENANCE));
    delayStack.add(new MyCard("Northern", MyCard.LINE_AVAILABLE));

    // create a stack
    CardStack activeStack = new CardStack();
    activeStack.setTitle("Active Tube Lines");

    // add cards to stack
    activeStack.add(new MyCard("Jubilee Line", MyCard.LINE_HIDE_STATUS));
    activeStack.add(new MyCard("Victoria Line", MyCard.LINE_HIDE_STATUS));

    // add stack to cardView
    mCardView.addStack(delayStack);
    mCardView.addStack(activeStack);

    // draw cards
    mCardView.refresh();

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(
        com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item) {

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private class DownloadFeedsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            saveToSdCard();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        String response = "";

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = getDataFromSDcard(); // getting XML
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
        // looping through all item nodes <item>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_NAME, e.getAttribute(KEY_NAME));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            menuItems.add(map);
        }

        // Adding menuItems to ListView
        // adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
        // mCtx,
        // menuItems,
        // R.layout.list_item,
        // new String[] { KEY_ADVERT, KEY_CONTACT, KEY_DATE },
        // new int[] { R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3 });

        return response;
    }

    private String getDataFromSDcard() {
        // Get data from SDCard
        // Find the directory for the SD Card using the API
        // *Don't* hardcode "/sdcard"
        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        // Get the text file
        File file = new File(sdcard, "Folder/test.xml");

        // Read text from file
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(line);
                text.append('\n');
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // You'll need to add proper error handling here
        }
        return text.toString();
    }

    private void saveToSdCard() throws IOException {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(TUBE_STATUS_URL);
            URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
            conexion.connect();
            int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
            InputStream is = url.openStream();
            File testDirectory = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Folder");
            if (!testDirectory.exists()) {
                testDirectory.mkdir();
            }
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(testDirectory
                    + "/test.xml");
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            int count = 0;
            long total = 0;
            int progress = 0;
            while ((count = is.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                int progress_temp = (int) total * 100 / lenghtOfFile;
                if (progress_temp % 10 == 0 && progress != progress_temp) {
                    progress = progress_temp;
                }
                fos.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            is.close();
            fos.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.valueOf(menuItems.size()),
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // Log.d("Commuter+", String.valueOf(menuItems.size()));
    }
}
   }
```

And my XMLParser class:

```
public class XMLParser {

public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;

    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return XML
    return xml;
}
public Document getDomElement(String xml){
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is); 
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

    Log.d("Commuter+", String.valueOf(doc.toString().length()));
            // return DOM
        return doc;
}
public String getValue(Element item, String str) {      
    NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
    return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
}

public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
         Node child;
         if( elem != null){
             if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
                 for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                     if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                         return child.getNodeValue();
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         return "";
  }
  }
```

*I tried fixing this by testing my code with other URLs that had XML data and it worked, but there seems to be a problem when I use this URL.*

Comment: `parser.getDomElement(xml);` is likely returning `null`, thus leaving `Document doc` as `null`

Comment: @bas +1 Yes, I thought of that but couldn't find out how to fix that. But after using the debugger, I know that xml is not null, so I'm not sure where the null pointer is coming from.

Comment: if you say the NullPointerException is at line `NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);`, then `doc` must be `null`. Even if `getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM)` would return `null`, it wouldn't give a NullPointerException. It is not about xml being null, it is about `doc` being `null`.

Comment: Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Since `parser.getDomElement(xml);` returns null, I'd say the DOM-element that `xml` represents does not exist in the context of the parser.

Comment: The Document Object Model probably does not have whatever value `xml` is at that time. It does not exist. If you want further assistance, could you please post the value of `xml` before it throws the exception?

Comment: The value of xml before it throws the exception is exacly the same as this: http://cloud.tfl.gov.uk/TrackerNet/LineStatus

Comment: In that case it probably can't find the specific DOM element because you specify multiple elements. You have to loop through the DOM elements and then parse each individual element and add it to doc.

Comment: Sorry, how would I do that?

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

Comment: thanks, I'll try this tommorow and get back to you :D